# running test cases from a java class

Tags: java, junit4

I have say 10 test cases, and i want to run them from a java class, i can get the Junit's class name only at runtime. Is it possible to do so.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(Class<?>...)
```

It supports multiple test classes. From JUnit4.